# How to check whether a string array is a palindrome?

Tags: arrays, string, palindrome

I've come across a problem where a string array value such as ["cat", "dog", "cat"] is considered as a palindrome, and something like ["dog", "dog", "cat"] is not. How would I go about checking an array like such to return true if it is indeed a palindrome, or false, but here's the trickier part: without the .equals method?

Answer (score 0):

Check [this reference](https://howtodoinjava.com/java-examples/check-palindrome-string/), use the first way or approach, the second one uses equals method. The first way is to take two pointers, i and j. i is start of the array, j is end of array. At every iteration, increment i, decrement j, and check array content.
continue iteration while i<j